# How to stop MAVEN from combining the output of TestNg testcases in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

MAVEN combining the output of TestNg test cases.  These are 3 testcases should print two outputs, so total 6 results should be displayed by MAVEN:

**First Test case:**

```
@Test
public void BrowserAutomation()
{
System.out.println("BrowserAutomation");
}

@Test
public void elementsUi()
{
System.out.println("elementsUi");
}
```

**Second test case:**

```
@Test
public void postJira()
{
System.out.println("postJira");
}

@Test
public void deletesTwitter()
{
System.out.println("deletesTwitter");
}
```

**Third test case:**

```
@Test
public void NativeAppAndroid()
{
System.out.println("NativeAppAndroid");
}

@Test
public void IOSApps()
{
System.out.println("IOSApps");
}
```

Output when ran as TESTNg suite should look this:

- IOSApps
- NativeAppAndroid
- deletesTwitter
- postJira
- BrowserAutomation
- elementsUi

But MAVEN output look like this:

- IOSAppsNativeAppAndroiddeletesTwitter
- postJira
- BrowserAutomation
- elementsUi

Comment: Replace all `System.out.print(` with `System.out.println(`.

Comment: @howlger I done that, same result. :(